# How to Grant Access to specific API for a user in WSO2 API Manager?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I created a user with username:aggr1. When I log in to the dev portal with aggr1 credentials, I can access all of the published APIs. How can I force this particular user to only see two or three APIS in Dev Portal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maange access to APIs through roles.

When creating an API, on the first page you have a dropbox "Access" (or "Visibility" orsomething like that) with default value *All*.

You can list roles, which are required to see the Api in the dev portal. And then  assign (or not) the roles to the user.

Comment: I found it in "Design Configurations" page. it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

By default APIs are set to public and any user who logs into the devportal can see the APIs. You can set role-based visibility or based on domain. Please refer the documentation - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/design-api/advanced-topics/control-api-visibility-and-subscription-availability-in-developer-portal/#control-api-visibility-in-the-developer-portal